# How do I autopopulate a people picker based on another people picker value?

Tags: custom-list

I am new to sharepoint and I am having trouble creating a versatile list.  What I need is when an employee is entered into the people picker column I need their manager to autopopulate in another people picker column.

Can this be done?  If not are there any workarounds?  I ultimately need an email to be automatically sent to the persons manager when their name is entered into the sharepoint.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery we can acheive this.
Find the selected index or value from 1st People picker and With responsible to that pass the selected value to *userName* parameter.

Note: The Value must be the username.

`function SetUserFieldValue(fieldName, userName) {
 var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='" + fieldName + "']");
 var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id');
 var _PeoplePickerEditer = $("input[title='" + fieldName + "']");
 _PeoplePickerEditer.val(userName);
 var _PeoplePickerOject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId];
 _PeoplePickerOject.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);
}`